# android newRelic with AsyncTask

Tags: android, newrelic

I have a problem with newRelic when AsyncTask is in my android app. This is my log:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.activity.MainActivity$3 cannot be cast to com.newrelic.agent.android.api.v2.TraceFieldInterface

where $3 is instance of AsyncTask.

It only happens when AsyncTask is present in application. Have you any tips how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You're using a "this" in the wrong spot. Impossible to tell you more without code, but hard to imagine that it wouldn't be evident the moment you looked at code causing the exception.

Answer (score 9):

New Relic support engineer here,

We've identified the cause of this ClassCastException and deployed a fix which will be available in the next release of the agent. This should be available soon.

Keep your eyes on the Android agent release page here: http://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/android